# Accepting enums of multiple types in functions

Tags: function, swift, enums

```
enum CompassPoint: String, Printable {
    case North = "North"
    case South = "South"
    case East = "East"
    case West = "West"

    var description: String {
        get {
            return self.rawValue
        }
    }
}

enum Cars: String, Printable {
    case Audi = "Audi"
    case Lexus = "Lexus"
    case Volkswagen = "Volkwagen"
    case Jaguar = "Jaguar"

    var description: String {
        get {
            return self.rawValue
        }
    }
}

func someFunction(direction: CompassPoint) {
    println("\(direction)")
}

someFunction(.North) // prints out "North"
someFunction(.Audi) // error(CompassPoint.Type does not have member named 'Audi')
```

I'm trying to create a function in Swift which accepts both types of Enums, and maybe in the future others as well. Does anyone know how to create a function which accepts all Enums?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about making someFunction's argument type Printable? Like this:

```
func someFunction(typeToPrint: Printable) {
     println("\(typeToPrint)")
}
someFunction(CompassPoint.North)
someFunction(Cars.Audi)
```

Comment: Awesome! Been trying to find a way and focussed on the Enum itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use it like this by creating another enum which holds all the other enums

```
enum CompassPoint: String, Printable {
case North = "North"
case South = "South"
case East = "East"
case West = "West"

var description: String {
    get {
        return self.rawValue
    }
}
```

}

```
enum Cars: String, Printable {
case Audi = "Audi"
case Lexus = "Lexus"
case Volkswagen = "Volkwagen"
case Jaguar = "Jaguar"


var description: String {
    get {
        return self.rawValue
    }
}
```

}

```
enum combined
{
case comp(CompassPoint)
case car(Cars)
}


func someFunction(direction: combined) {
println("\(direction)")
}




someFunction(combined.comp(.North))// prints out "North"
someFunction(combined.car(.Audi))
```